# Should we allow doctors or God to heal us?

Tags: faith, healing

Inspired by [this post regarding moving mountains by faith](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/385/are-there-any-documented-instances-of-anyone-moving-a-mountain-in-faith).

God has told us to rely on him ([Matthew 6:25-34](http://www.watchtower.org/e/bible/mt/chapter_006.htm)) for all things.

Also, [James 5:15](http://www.watchtower.org/e/bible/jas/chapter_005.htm) says

> And the prayer of faith will make the indisposed one well, and Jehovah
>   will raise him up. Also, if he has committed sins, it will be forgiven
>   him.

So, since we should rely on God for all things and God will heal us, should we ever need to go to the doctor?

Similarly, since God is the source of all knowledge and wisdom, should we ever trust a doctor?

Comment: Per our [quality standards](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/725/why-was-my-question-closed-how-can-i-get-it-open-again), this question is far too broad to be constructive.  As it is, it's pitting one doctrinal group against another (those that say "Yes" -vs- those that say "No").  This turns this into a voting contest.  Therefore, I'm closing this as Not Constructive.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How does God heal?  Through whom does God offer healing and wholeness?

I know several health care professionals (including some physicians, nurses, and physical therapists) who chose  those demanding professions because they hope to serve as God's hands for the healing of their little part of the world.

So, my answer is "Yes, go to the doctor."

Comment: Christ never criticized Luke's profession, that we know of... If Christ thought doctors were not to be trusted, He surely had plenty of opportunity to tell us that.

Comment: @Flimzy back in Jesus' time, doctors didn't really know what they were doing.  Heck we still used leeches up until the 19th century for [bloodletting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodletting)

Comment: @Patrick: According to many, in modern times doctors don't really know what they are doing. :)

Comment: @Flimzy: I'll dispute that one anyday. If it hadn't been for two different teams of very competent doctors, I would have one brother who died soon after birth and another who can't walk.  Instead, they're both completely healthy today.

Comment: God uses means all the time to accomplish His ends - those means may be a doctor, or they may be a miracle ... but He [typically] *tends* towards the non-miraculous; if not, Paul would not have told Timothy to "take a little wine for your health", he would have told him "just pray, and God'll fix it"

Comment: Which leads to people going to a doctor, availing of medical expertise qcquired through years of training, and then attributing their recovery to God, which strikes me as ungrateful.