# Should we accept blood transfusions?

Tags: mosaic-law, healing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blood transfusions and Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/410/blood-transfusions-and-christianity)

The Bible makes it known that blood is Holy, it is what gives us life. The Jehovah's Witnesses seem to think that a person should not accept another living creature's blood; I am aware that they use scripture to back up this claim.

Is there any scripture to suggest the contrary of this idea? Is it more important that we reject a blood transfusion to give God glory, or should we fight for life in order to give God glory?