# What are some situations documented outside of the Bible in which God intervened in human affairs?

Tags: intervention

As a continuance of [whether we can truly know anything about God's affairs](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/can-we-truly-know-anything-about-gods-character) and also [whether all Christian views need a Biblical basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/do-all-christian-views-need-to-have-a-biblical-basis), I was curious if there were any instances of God's influence on humanity that are not mentioned in the Bible. On a basic level, many people like to believe that God intervenes from time to time in answering prayers; surely all the ones post-Bible aren't documented in the Bible (like, if you had a prayer answered yesterday, obviously it's not in the Bible). I'm looking for something a bit more substantive than small answered prayers though, like God revealing himself to a group of people or something of that nature, which isn't strictly found in the Bible but most/many/some Christians hold the event to be true in the Christian lore.

**What are some of the situations accepted by Christians in which God performed some act, or revealed himself, or otherwise influenced mankind in some way that is not mentioned in the Bible (if any)?**

Comment: Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-evidence-exists-for-modern-day-miracles

Comment: Is it possible for God to intervene and have it not be considered a miracle?  If so, how do we know it was God?  Because of this line of reasoning, I think this is an exact duplicate of [What evidence exists for modern day miracles?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-evidence-exists-for-modern-day-miracles)

Comment: @Flimzy & Richard: I would divorce the two concepts (intervention/revealing himself and miracles), especially if He doesn't do anything but show himself. Some people, for example, claim they saw God in the sky at some point—along with dozens of other people—but he didn't actually *do* anything. I'm not sure I would call that a miracle. If there is an event like that in some Christian lore, especially one in which more than one person witness, that would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, so you're looking for accounts that intervene in human affairs, but aren't miraculous?  These seem to be contradictory.  Are you just looking for stories?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for theophanies?

Comment: Please make each question stand on it's own. You shouldn't have to start with two "read first" links as a lead in to a question. If you want to include them for further reading in a post script that's fine, but please word questions as stand alone entities. SE guys have broken us off about this before and closed some questions over it. Thanks!

Comment: For *most Christians*, the answer is the empty set. For *some Christians*, this is a list question. Voting to close.

Comment: @dancek: You should make that an answer, especially if you can expand on that "list" you mention, because it seems you know something that others don't. Either way, I don't see how this is not a valid question; it is a real problem and it has a definite answer: either yes or no. It seems—from the paucity of responses—that the answer is 'no' but because no one has *actually* answered, it leads me to believe that most people are unsure.

Comment: I meant that if we only allow interventions that *most Christians* approve of, there are none. If we allow those that a notable, but minor part of Christians (say, >1M people) believe were genuine interventions, we get way too many to list. (As you might know, asking for lists is frowned upon on SE.)

Comment: I don't really understand the list concept being applied here. So I wrote your answer down below that answers my question in a way that is exactly as I was looking for it. ^_^ Would you say my answer is accurate to what you were trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is challenging to get ***all*** Christians to believe in anything *together*; with all the different denominations each has their own particular views of God, of the Trinity, of the validity of each of the various stories in the Bible. Did the flood actually happen? Or is an anecdote, simply there to teach us a lesson? Can a man really live inside of a really big fish? Or was it a whale? Which translation is most accurate?

The learned Christian finds that although all Christian men of faith believe in the same God, they vary in the **extent** of their beliefs. That said, some *particular* beliefs may be shared more widely than others; for example, the idea that God is *all-powerful*, *all-knowing*, and *all-loving* is a belief that is probably shared among the great majority of Christians, regardless of denomination. Regarding the question being asked here—**whether there is any generally shared belief involving God's intervention in human affairs that is outside Biblical documentation**—the simple answer is "**No**". There is no widely shared belief in any event in which God revealed himself or otherwise intervened in human affairs that is documented outside the Bible. There are some denominations, however, that do profess such beliefs, but they make up a relatively small minority of the Christian whole and as such cannot be taken as representative of the "average" person of Christian faith.

source: [dancek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/60/dancek)